# Unfamiliar with some notations of BdG Hamiltonian

Tags: superconductivity, second-quantization, majorana-fermions

In a paper [Majorana Fermions in Equilibrium and in Driven Cold-Atom Quantum Wires](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5367). The authors come to a Hamiltonian for BdG, eqn(2).
$$ H = \sum_{p} a_{p}^{\dagger}(\epsilon'_{p}-\mu+u p \sigma_{z}+B\sigma_{x})a_{p}+(\Delta a_{p,\uparrow
}^{\dagger}a_{-p,\downarrow
}^{\dagger} +h.c.)$$

what is baffling me is that I try to write this in Nambu spinor notation but couldn't seem to get the desired spectrum.
This is what I got($^{*}$prone to mistakes)
\begin{bmatrix}
    \epsilon'_{p}-\mu+u p       & B & 0 & \Delta \\
    B       & \epsilon'_{p}-\mu-u p & \Delta & 0 \\
    0       & \Delta^{*} & \epsilon'_{p}-\mu+u p & B \\
    \Delta^{*}       & 0 & B & \epsilon'_{p}-\mu-u p
\end{bmatrix}
I couldn't seem to find the mistake, my ignorance.
Sorry for this trivial question.

Comment: Please write the Hamiltonian in full, including the sum over $p$ and the multiplications by matrices. You will realise that the bottom-right sector corresponds to operators $a_{-p}$ (and the associated creation operator) and not $a_{p}$. Hence the term $up$ should get a minus sign in the bottom-right corner. In fact $\epsilon_{-p}$ should appear as well. Usually this is simplified due to symmetry $\epsilon_{-p}=\epsilon_{p}$, but this has to be check as well. Also $\Delta$ is $p$-dependent in general. In short : you completely failed to write $H$ in the Nambu space.

Comment: @FraSchelle Thanks for the valuable comments. You mean to say that, $\Psi=(a_{p}^{\dagger},a_{p},a_{-p},a_{-p}^{\dagger})^{\dagger}$?

Comment: Yes exactly, you have $H=\sum_{p}a_{p}^{\dagger}\left(\cdots\right)a_{p}+\Delta a_{p}^{\dagger}a_{-p}^{\dagger}+\cdots$ in your text, then you wrote a big matrix. But this matrix is nothing but the object $\left[\cdots\right]$ in the notation $H=\sum_{p}\Psi_{p}^{\dagger}\left[\cdots\right]\Psi_{p}$, where $H$ is the same as before, and $\Psi$ is what you wrote. So, what is $\left[\cdots\right]$ ? Yours is not the correct one because you miss the $a_{-p}$ in $\Psi$, so $up$ should change to $-up$ in the bottom right corner of $\left[\cdots\right]$, ...